# All divs change position based on max div size in parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating this sorting visualizer app in React. I've got everything down, but my rendering is a bit "jiggly".

Here's what I mean by this: My structure of the graph looks like this (also I'm using bootstrap4):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- -->
<div class="graph" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
  <div class="bar" title="56" style="height: 224px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 107, 160); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="104" style="height: 416px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(42, 184, 255); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="65" style="height: 260px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 186); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="6" style="height: 24px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 11, 17); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="51" style="height: 204px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 97, 146); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="31" style="height: 124px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 59, 89); display: inline-block;"></div>
  ...
</div>
<!-- -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This content changes based on the changes to the list. The heights and colors are calculated from the height of the container in proportion to the numeric value.

What I've noticed is that all the bars "jump up" when there isn't a .bar that is the entire height of the container. How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` isn't suitable here because you have to deal with vertical alignment and linebox tricks. Since you are using bootstrap, you can rely on flexbox and add two classes:

```css
.graph  {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.graph > *{
  margin:0 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- -->
<div class="graph d-flex align-items-end" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
  <div class="bar" title="56" style="height: 224px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 107, 160); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="104" style="height: 416px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(42, 184, 255); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="65" style="height: 260px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 186); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="6" style="height: 24px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 11, 17); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="51" style="height: 204px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 97, 146); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="31" style="height: 124px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 59, 89); display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With `inline-block` you will have to either make the line-height bigger and adjust the alignment

```css
.graph  {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.graph > *{
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- -->
<div class="graph" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; line-height:500px;">
  <div class="bar" title="56" style="height: 224px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 107, 160); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="104" style="height: 416px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(42, 184, 255); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="65" style="height: 260px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 186); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="6" style="height: 24px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 11, 17); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="51" style="height: 204px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 97, 146); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="31" style="height: 124px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 59, 89); display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or add hidden element that you make `height:100%`

```css
.graph  {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.graph:before{
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- -->
<div class="graph" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
  <div class="bar" title="56" style="height: 224px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 107, 160); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="104" style="height: 416px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(42, 184, 255); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="65" style="height: 260px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 186); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="6" style="height: 24px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 11, 17); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="51" style="height: 204px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 97, 146); display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div class="bar" title="31" style="height: 124px; width: 4px; background-color: rgb(0, 59, 89); display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```